# brilliant_gallery is not showing images

Tags: media, javascript

I tried to use brilliant_gallery, its working but not showing images. instead thats showing only black background.

I am writing what exactly I did..

1. I installed lightbox2 as dependency of brilliant_gallery
2. then I installed brilliant_gallery
3. then I created albums in sites/default/files
4. then I created images in sites/default/files/album; and copied some images in that
5. then I went to Input format and enabled Full HTML format to recognize Brilliant Gallery Tag
6. in admin/config/brilliant_gallery/settings i added "albums" in Main gallery folder
7. added a new text field to basic content type to add the path of image folder. in display option i set brilliant gallery option for display
8. while create new node i am putting path of image directory as "images"

Could anyone tell me where I have missed something? I am not able to see images but instead I am seeing black background.

thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same issue! I'm using altervista as web hosting Did you solve it already?

Comment: i was unable to solve this